# Change language of installation DVD

Tags: installation

I have downloaded Ubuntu and burned the ISO to DVD. When the disk opens, it is in Dutch (I think) and doesn't seem to have any options for changing to English.

I tried installing it via Windows XP Add Program (control panel) but can't find a setup file.

I tried booting from the DVD, but my Acer Aspire One doesn't seem to like that. It runs on a Crucial 256GB SSD and the start-up screen only lasts for a fraction of a second, meaning I can't press the F2 at the 'crucial' moment!

Any ideas?

Comment: If my memory serves well, acer provides a windows utility to set bios boot settings. Set boot device priority to CD/DVD and try booting again.

Answer (score 1):

To change Language:

1. Boot from your Media which has the Ubuntu ISO
2. Wait for the LiveCD / LiveUser to load
3. By Default you will get a window pop asking to Install or Try Ubuntu
4. On this menu you will have option to change Language

If above does not work for you:
Suggest you download a fresh ISO from Ubuntu.com

For BOOT Menu:

If you are using Win8, it has tendency to boot real quick. Thus switch off your laptop (no restart) and press the power on button and F2 key almost with a littel delay- make sure you start with power on first.

These worked for me in a test Laptop (Sony Vaio E)